# Get tag out of html with C#?

Tags: c#, html, tags

i have this html tag:

```
<img src="/Student/ExaminationImage?name=figuur" />
```

and i want to strip it in just this :/Student/ExaminationImage?name=figuur
and a second string with : figuur

How do i do this?

I tried everything but nothing works well.

Grtz

Comment: Just in case you're leaning towards regex, don't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 =)

Answer (score 6):

The [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) is a good tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: Yes i see, this could be fine. but what i have is a string. And not a document.. So i have a string with al this html code in it...

Answer (score 2):

You could always use linq to xml if it's always well formed XML

```
string imageTag = "<img src=\"\/Student\/ExaminationImage?name=figuur\" />"

string src = XElement.Parse(imageTag ).Attribute("src").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Albin's answer:

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a very robust, reliable way to handle this, and really is the way to go.

However, **if and only if** you can guarantee that your tag is a) already isolated in a string, and b) always of the same format as you've described, you can use this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tag = @"<img src=""/Student/ExaminationImage?name=figuur"" />";

        Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}", tag);

        var tagParts = tag.Split(new[] {'"'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var src = tagParts[1];

        Console.WriteLine("Src: {0}", src);

        var srcParts = src.Split('?');

        Console.WriteLine("Parameters: {0}", srcParts[1]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```